# how to access content of docker 1.13.0 container on windows 10

Tags: docker, windows-10

I try to figure out how to setup docker for local web development.
I want to add and modify files as i can in normal way.

SO:  how to access content of docker 1.13.0 container on windows 10 ?

Comment: Too vague question. https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/

Comment: I already read manual but i can't find way how to get inside container to edit files. I want ot use docker on development machine for drupal development and need access to the folders of drupal instalation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- solution for future readers:

  - in docker settings->shared drives
    ->check drive you want to share
  - after that for eg. to mount drupal folder **themes** (/var/www/html/themes), for windows location eg. : **e:/dockerprojects/drupal/themes**  run this command:

> docker run -v e:/dockerprojects/drupal/themes:/var/www/html/themes --name drupal6 drupal

you have to create all needed windows folder before creation of container